# D/DP/DQ Parameters in RSA Cryptography

Tags: encryption, cryptography, rsa

I see some parameters in RSA cryptography such as  `D / DP/ DQ P and Q` what this parameters really do is it some kind of padding for the cipher text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These parameters are used to speed up the private key operations using the Chinese remainder theorem.
The [wikipedia article on RSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA) describes how this is done.

Comment: Well the last four are used for speed up, sure.